# Laravel: Login system problem for learning

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make a login for learning, so I followed a video from youtube with the same coding. It should be able to check the format of the inputted data, check whether user already login or not, check whether user accessing the next page wihthout login,  but in the end, it will always only showed email and password required errors even if I already inputted the right input. Please help. Here are my codes.

web.php

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

  Route::get('/main', 'MainController@index');

  Route::post('/main/checklogin', 'MainController@checklogin');

  Route::get('main/successlogin', 'MainController@successlogin');

  Route::get('main/logout', 'MainController@logout');
```

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Login</title>

   <!--CSS-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
   <script type="text/javascript" src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="login-page-frame">
      <div class="header-login-page-frame">
        <h3>Login</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-login-form-frame">
           @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
               <script>window.location="/main/successlogin";</script>
           @endif

           @if($message = Session::get('error'))
               <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                  <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
               </div>
           @endif
           @if(count($errors) > 0)
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
              </div>
           @endif
           <form method="post" action="{{ url('/main/checklogin') }}" class="login-form">
               {{ csrf_field() }}
               <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="login-email" class="form-control">
               <br>
               <input type="password" placeholder="pass" name="login-password" class="form-control">
               <br>
               <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn-login" value="login">
           </form>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

halamanUtama.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Halaman Utama</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container box">
         <h3 align="center">Selamat Datang</h3>
         <br />
         @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
            <div class="alert alert-danger success-block">
               <strong>Welcome {{ Auth::user()->email }}</strong>
               <br />
               <a href="{{ url('/main/logout/') }}">Logout</a>
            </div>
         else
            <script>window.location="/main";</script>
         @endif
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

MainController.php

```
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Validator;
   use Auth;
   use Input;
   class MainController extends Controller
   {
      //
      function index(){
         return view('login');
      }

      function checklogin(Request $request){
         $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
         ]);

         $user_data=array(
            'email' => $request->get('login-email'),
            'password' => $request->get('login-password')
         );

         if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('main/successlogin');
         }else{
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
         }

      }

      function successlogin(){
         return view('halamanUtama');
      }

      function logout(){
         Auth::logout();
         return redirect('main');
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on whether any of your other code works, but the cause of your validation errors is that the name of your form inputs does not match the name of the fields you are trying to validate.

In your form, your inputs are called `login-email` and `login-password`. However, in your controller, you are validating that a field called `email` and a field called `password` are provided (because they are required).

So either change your form names to `email` and `password` or change your validation fields to `login-email` and `login-password`.

Comment: I've tried it and it worked. Never thought the email and password in the rules are actually the name of my inputs. Thanks dude.